# How to return default DataPointStyle?

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml, styles

By default `ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle` is quite good but the label of it is not visible.

So I have applied custom style to make visible data point label but after this the default style now is looking ugly.

How to return default data point style and make visible data point  label at the same time? THANK YOU!

Here is my XAML:

```
 <toolkit:ColumnSeries  Title="Male" ItemsSource="{Binding MaleSerie}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding ItemName}"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Count}"   ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Count}"
            AnimationSequence="Simultaneous"  
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="304" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="266">

            <toolkit:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
                <Style TargetType="toolkit:ColumnDataPoint">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:ColumnDataPoint">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Rectangle
                            Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            Stroke="Black"/>
                                    <Grid  Background="#aaffffff"  Margin="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                        <TextBlock  FontSize="10" Text="{TemplateBinding FormattedDependentValue}"  FontWeight="Bold" Width="Auto" Margin="2"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </toolkit:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>

        </toolkit:ColumnSeries>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For standard Silverlight control you can usually find the default style from MSDN.

Example: ComboBox default template:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334408(v=vs.95).aspx

For the toolkit you probably need to download the source code, copy then modify what you need.